# how to build the logic for following mentioned iterative loop?

Tags: python

```
row = int(input("Please enter the row: "))
row=row+1
for i in range(1,row):
    for j in range (i,row):
        print (j, end='')
    for k in range (1,i):
        print(k,end='')
    print()
```

I have tried the above-mentioned code for printing:

```
12345
23451
34512
45123
51234
```

But what I want to print is both row and column values should not be static and should be taken from the user.

input:

```
row = 8
column = 5
```

output:

```
12345
23451
34512
45123
51234
12345
23451
34512
```

how can we solve this?

Comment: Note that your expected output has **8 rows** and **5 columns**, not the other way round. I have fixed this in your question.

Comment: As for the answer to your question, I encourage you to give it some thought: which loop handles the creation of rows? Which one does columns? Does it make sense to iterate over `i in range(1, row)`  and `j in range(i, row)`? Which loop do you think you need to change to show the number of columns you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to `input` two different numbers, and use them both in your loops.

```
row = int(input("Rows: "))
col = int(input("Columns: "))
for i in range(row):
    print("".join(f"{(j+i)%col+1}" for j in range(col)))
```

```
Rows: 8
Columns: 5
12345
23451
34512
45123
51234
12345
23451
34512
```